# Grep text between two patterns on each line including the pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Have these lines:

```
[2022-04-14T20:06:17+0800] [ALPM] installed data (0.5.0-7)
[2022-04-14T20:06:17+0800] [ALPM] installed data-cleo (0.4.1-4)
[2022-04-14T20:06:17+0800] [ALPM] installed python (0.2.2-11)
```

Would like to get only the packages and separated by spaces instead of newline:

```
data data-cleo python
```

Comment: `awk -v ORS=' ' '{print $4}' log.txt`

Comment: @Fravadona best answer so far!!!

Comment: @Fravadona's comment is good (if it was an answer, I'd upvote it), but if the log file can contain entries other than "installed", use something like `awk  -v ORS=' ' '$3 == "installed" {print $4}'`.  BTW, I often use awk commands like this to extract package names from /var/log/dpkg.log on my debian system - dpkg.log has a similar format to your log file, and $3 can contain words like "install", "upgrade", "purge", "remove", "configure", etc.  I usually want to know things like what packages were installed (or upgraded, or removed) on a certain date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '$3=="installed"{ printf "%s%s", sep, $4; sep=OFS } END{ print "" }' file
data data-cleo python
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged your question `linux`, I'll assume you have GNU grep with its `-P` PCRE option. Then

```
$ grep -Po 'installed\s+\K\S+' log.txt | paste -sd ' '
data data-cleo python
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's the answer.

```
cat log.txt | sed -n 's/.*installed //p' | sed 's/ (.*//p' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: There is no reason to pipe `cat` into `sed`. The file can be used as an argument to `sed`. There also isn't any need to call `sed` multiple times or to pipe it into `tr` as `sed` itself can be used to convert `\n` into a space.

Comment: What's your solution then?

Comment: My answer would be what's in cas's comment which is a modification of what's in Fravadona's comment. Had Fravadona not already added it as a comment, then I'd post what cas has as an answer and had either of them added what they have as a comment. I commented on your answer to let you know how it can be done differently rather than downvoting it.

Comment: @NasirRiley stuff in comments is fair game under the "you snooze, you lose" rule. Only actual answers count.  Feel free to "steal" my comment and turn it into an answer.

Comment: @NasirRiley you can modify any code you want here, it's not someone's property.

Comment: @Smeterlink Or you can. It doesn't benefit me to do it as I already know how it can be done.

Comment: Among other issues (UUOC and you don't need 2 calls to `sed` and multiple pipes for this) that will produce output that isn't a valid text file per POSIX as it won't have a terminating newline and so whatever any subsequent text processing tool does with it is undefined behavior. It'll also add a trailing blank char which is probably undesirable.

Comment: FYI `sed -n 's/.*installed //p' | sed 's/ (.*//p'` can be written using a single call to sed as `sed -n 's/.*installed \([^ ]*\) (.*/\1/p'`